# Previous plots overlaps with new plots using matplotlib interactive

Tags: matplotlib, interactive, python-interactive

**Escenario**
I want to update the values of a heatmap with a time delay of 1 seconds. The objective is represent the evolution of the Q-Table in a reinforcement learning problem.

**Error**
The problem is that the heatmap figure is being updated but the values are kept intead of replaced.
[image]

**Code**
*Q is intially an all-zeros pandas DatraFrame*
Function to create seaborn heatmap:

```
# Helper functions to draw, update and get values of the table
def draw_Table(Q):
    table = sns.heatmap(Q, cmap='Blues', annot=True, linewidths=.5, cbar=False, 
                linecolor='black', square=True).set_title('Q-Table')
    return table
```

Here is the main functionality:

```
plt.ion()
plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
for i in range(EPISODES):

    print('Episode [{}/{}]'.format(i,EPISODES))
    print('Current Q-Table')

    # Some code that updates the values of Q

    # Update the new Q-Value
    if 'previous' in globals(): del previous
    previous = draw_Table(Q)
    plt.pause(1)

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Looks like you are deleting the title in each iteration. Not sure if that is useful. Instead you would want to return the axes and `clear` (not delete) the axes. (Note that with a [mcve], I could also provide an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Solution (according to comments) was found clearing the axes with:

```
# Update the new Q-Value
if 'previous' in globals(): 
    previous.axes.clear()
previous = draw_Table(Q)
```

*[This was edited out of the question into an answer]*